# How to use currentFrame/totalFrames Properly AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs6

Hey everyone been researching this for a bit now and can't seem to figure it out.

Basically what I'm trying to do is when my `introScreen` is the done with its animation I want to remove the `introScreen` and add the `startScreen` because both Movie Clip object contain animations and I dont want one to start while the other is still going on. So I am trying to use the Frame properties to check this condition and execute it.

This is what I have so far but it does nothing but play the `introScreen` and just stays on that screen.

```
//Start Game Screen
        introScreen = new mcIntroScreen();
        stage.addChild(introScreen);
        introScreen.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2);
        introScreen.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2);

        if (introScreen.currentFrame == introScreen.totalFrames)
        {
            stage.removeChild(introScreen);

            //Start Game Screen
            startScreen = new mcStartGameScreen();
            stage.addChild(startScreen);
            startScreen.x = (stage.stageWidth / 2);
            startScreen.y = (stage.stageHeight / 2);
            trace(startScreen + "startscreenADDED");
            startScreen.addEventListener("PLAY_AGAIN", playGameAgain, false, 0, true);

            startScreen.addEventListener("TIME_ATTACK", timeAttackMode, false, 0, true);
        }
```

Maybe someone can help clear this up for me I thought the current code means that if the current frame plays through and reaches the total frames in the animation then the condition would be satisfied I tried tracing it as well but nothing comes up. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to put the frame check within an `Event.ENTER_FRAME` handler. As it is now, unless you left out some code, it only checks once immediately after it creates the `introScreen`, which of course means its still on frame 1. Try something like this:

```
// Start Game Screen
introScreen = new mcIntroScreen();
// etc

addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, introEnterFrameHandler);

function introEnterFrameHandler(e:Event):void {
    if (introScreen.currentFrame == introScreen.totalFrames)
    {
        removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, introEnterFrameHandler);
        stage.removeChild(introScreen);
        // etc
    }
}
```

Note that this will mean the very last frame won't really be seen. You could use `Event.EXIT_FRAME` to let the last frame display before handling the ending.

Also, the way I usually do this is a little different. Instead of tracking the playback with `Event.ENTER_FRAME` I dispatch an event at the end of my timeline. Example:

```
// on the last frame of the symbol timeline
dispatchEvent(new Event("introComplete", true));
```

Then I can simply handle it as a custom event:

```
// Start Game Screen
introScreen = new mcIntroScreen();
// etc
addEventListener("introComplete", introCompleteHandler);
function introCompleteHandler(e:Event):void {
    stage.removeChild(introScreen);
    // etc
}
```

Comment: Wow of course. Thank you so much for this Aaron I appreciate it. Thanks for the extra info on event handlers ill definitely take that into consideration. Won't forget next time.